# How to find placeholder with 2 states: clear and class="error"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Im testing the ContactUs form. 
And there is 2 states for placeholders in fields. 
First state - when nothing is filled in.

```
<label for="edit-submitted-name">Name </label>
```

Second state - when form was sending with validation error.

```
<label for="edit-submitted-name" class="error">Name </label>
```

I want to check, that after sending class="error" is appearing or not.

Here is how I tried to do it:

```
if (driver.getPageSource().contains("error")) {
        System.out.println("Validation down");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Validation okay");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate if `class="error"` is present or not you can use the following solution:

- Using `cssSelector`:

  ```
  try {
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for='edit-submitted-name']:not(.error)"))
      System.out.println("Validation okay");
  }
  catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      System.out.println("Validation down");
  }
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  try {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='edit-submitted-name' and not(@class='error')]"))
      System.out.println("Validation okay");
  }
  catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      System.out.println("Validation down");
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Works for now.

Answer (score 2):

You can get multiple instances of `error` strings in your page source, it's better to explicitly identify unique element so there would be no false positive matches.

Here is how it can be done using XPath locators:

1. Label where nothing is filled in:

   ```
   //label[@for='edit-submitted-name' and not(@class='error')]
   ```

   [image]
2. Label with the validation error:

   ```
   //label[@for='edit-submitted-name' and @class='error']
   ```

   [image]

Example Java code which checks validation error presence:

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[@for='edit-submitted-name' @class='error']")).size() > 0) {
    System.out.println("Validation error is present.");
}
```

More information:

- [XSLT/XPath Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath)
- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using a simple CSS selector, please see the following

Normal state

```html
label[for='edit-submitted-name']
```

Error state

```html
 

   label[for='edit-submitted-name'].error
```